# NetBeans code-template expansion; string manipulation

Tags: templates, netbeans-7, freemarker

I'm trying to use the [Code Templates](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html) feature with PHP in NetBeans (7.3), however I'm finding it rather limited. Given the following desired output:

```
public function addFoo(Foo $foo) { 
    $this->fooCollection[] = $foo;
}
```

I'm trying to have every instance of "`foo`"/"`Foo`" be variable; so I used a variable:

```
public function add${name}(${name} $$${name}) {
    $this->${name}Collection[] = $$${name};
}
```

Of course, when expanded there isn't any regard given to the desired capitalization rules, because I can't find a way to implement that; the result being (*given I populate `${name}` with "`Foo`"*):

```
public function addFoo(Foo $Foo) { // note the uppercase "Foo" in the argument
    $this->FooCollection[] = $Foo; // and collection property names...
}                                  // not what I had in mind
```

Now, I've read that NetBeans supports [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) in it's templates, but that seems to be only for *file*-templates and not *snippet*-templates like these.

As far as I can tell, the FreeMarker version would look something like the following; however, it doesn't work, and `${name?capitalize}` is simply seen as another variable name.

```
public function add${name?capitalize}(${name?capitalize} $$${name}) {
    $this->${name}Collection[] = $$${name};
}
```

<sup>Passing "`foo`", allowing capitalize to fix it for type-names, second-words, etc.</sup>

**Is there any way to get FreeMarker support here, or an alternative?**

I'm open to any suggestions really; third-party plugins included. I just don't want to have to abandon NetBeans.

---

**Addendum**

The example given is trivial; an obvious solution for it specifically would be:

```
public function add${upperName}(${upperName} $$${lowerName}) {
    $this->${lowerName}Collection[] = $$${lowerName};
}
```

Where upper/lower would be "`Foo`"/"`foo`" respectively. However, it's just an example, and I'm looking for something more robust in general (*such as FreeMarker support*)